# HTTP status code for this case (400 or 422)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-status-codes

I have some method that looks like this

```
def some_method
   if params["status"] == "good"
      some action
      render json: {message: "action success"}, status: 200
   else 
      render json: {message: "The status is not good, try again later when the status is good"}, status: 200
   end
end
```

You see when the status is not good, currently i'm returning 200 status code, what is the best status code for this case. Is it 400 or 422?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I build API, usually I use 422 aka :unprocessable_entity for validation errors.

In my opinion, :unprocessable_entity looks more explicit.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer, this is validation error too so i think i'm gonna use 422

Answer (score 4):

And the description of [422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) says:

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.

So, in summary, it depends on your use case details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case both the request type and the syntax is correct. I just add some validation that if the status is not good then don't execute the action. So is it safe to assume that 422 is okay to use in this situation?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct means the server understands the request so that 400 is inappropriate. The status does not meet the expected conditions sounds like a good reason for 422.

Answer (score 0):

Loadd64!

A list of [HTTP Status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is available on Wikipedia and should be extremely helpful to you. If this is authenticating user input, then the correct status code would be `401`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't think :unauthorized is the right code